# Why is my sublimetxt3 giving error while loading static images?

Tags: python-3.7, django-1.10

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
 <title>DJANGO PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>
 <H1>Hello this is index.html</H1>
 <h1>Hi this contains an image also</h1>
 <img src="{% static "images/abc.jpg" %}">
</body>
</html>
```

This is my index.html.It is unable to fetch the static image from my settings.py

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFLDQ.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/843nR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you load staticfiles but you have used static

```
<img src="{% staticfiles "images/abc.jpg" %}">
```

Comment: Actually changing it to both the places as 'static' fixed my issue.Thank you.